# CE Image {height} & {width} variables outputting incorrectly

Tags: variable, ce-image

I'm using CE Image 2.4.5 on EE 2.9.3 and it outputs the image cropped correctly. However I also need the {height} and {width} variables elsewhere. The problem is that both of these variables are ouputting the original value and not the cropped value as suggested by the docs.

For example this code:

```
<p>{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" width="300" height="100" url_only="no" crop="yes" quality="100"}h: {height} {height_orig}, w: {width} {width_orig}, u: {made}{/exp:ce_img:pair}</p>
```

outputs the following:

```
<p>h: 614 614, w: 480 480, u: /path/to/d1small_300_100_c1.jpeg</p>
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Know this sounds odd - but since you are manually specifying the width and height of the image in the ce_img tag, why do you need ce_img to tell you what the cropped width and height are...?

Comment: Using a lazy loading script that needs the images height/width. The code above was me testing to find out why it wasn't really working. The real code only sets width and let's ce image set the height,thus I don't know the dimensions of images.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the following without any issue:

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{logo}" height="75" width="150"}
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAI=" data-original="{sized}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="{title}">
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```

Ensure that the cache folder for the resized images has the correct permissions. I believe that folder defaults to /images/sized

If the permissions are not correct, then the image doesn't get resized and I believe the resized width and height remain as the original width and height.

Comment: No -that does not work it outputs this:

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAI=" data-original="/path/to/DB_Portraits-40_50_75.jpg" width="1000" height="1500" alt="">

Comment: The image in "/path/to/DB_Portraits-40_50_75.jpg" is properly resized to 50x75 and exists?

Comment: Yes it does exist.

Comment: …and for completeness, when you preview "/path/to/DB_Portraits-40_50_75.jpg" directly in the browser, it shows as being 50x75 and not the original size of 1000x1500? We need to ensure that the server actually had the memory to resize the image properly.

Comment: Yes, just checked locally

Comment: Just realized I'm running EE 2.11.3 (20160726). Can you upgrade EE to 2.11.3 and see if that helps. I've re-installed CE Image 2.4.5 just to ensure I had the latest working version and my template snippet above works fine here.

Comment: Can't upgrade at the moment, but it is something I've proposed for this site.